# When making a Shiny App, where does your Data Frame live?

Tags: r, shiny

If I have a csv file that I want to be a part of a reactive shiny app,  where does my csv file need to exist, and what part of the code needs to call it?  Can it exist on AWS?

Does it need to exist in the "www" folder with images?  Does it need to be called inside the server?  And what if I want to deploy it to shinyapps.io?

Any quick help would be amazing. Thanks a ton.

(This is probably a simple question, but I've been through numerous tutorials and samples and just haven't found an answer.)

Comment: put it in the app folder or any subfolder. If you deploy with rstudio, it will be deployed as well